# Select PHP Framework for Legacy Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, web-frameworks

I'm new to PHP frameworks, and I want to reorganize a legacy website written with legacy PHP into a PHP framework (Laravel, Codeigniter, etc).

One problem is that the website is on shared hosting and is running PHP 5.3.29.

I'd want to get advice if it's better to:

(1) Choose an old version of an easier to use and modern framework, e.g., Laravel 4.1

(2) Choose a recent version of an outdated framework, e.g., Codeigniter

(3) Let it be, and keep adding new stuff on top of the old PHP files?

Comment: I'd choose 4) Replace the hosting and use a modern framework.

Comment: Replace the hosting simply on the PHP version cap -- 5.3 is just not good enough, regardless of framework. PHP 5.3 end-of-ife was [***over 4 years ago***](http://php.net/eol.php).

Answer (score 0):

First, you must update / refactor your code and change the hosting of a new one using the newest version of packages you need, not only for the code, but also for the security patches for these packages.

Still, if you need to use this old hosting, personally, I would use [Slim-v1](https://github.com/hectnandez/Slim/tree/1.6.7)